# How to update content of a file in Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, crud, firebase-storage

I have uploaded a file via [Firebase Storage API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files). At some point later, I want to update its content.

Example

1. Suppose I uploaded ***a.js*** with initial content as `console.log('v1')`
2. Later I want to update its content as `console.log('v2')`.

I have the new content as `String (or var)` in my Js code. How to achieve this with Firebase Web API for Storage.

PS: If you need the code for uploading a file, it is exactly similar to code present in [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files)

Comment: Have not tried `firebase`, though you should be able to use `FileReader` to read file as text; edit contents of file, create new `Blob` or `File` object from edited content then call `.put(file);`